# Unit testing a method with two database queries. Should I be stubbing out database calls? Rails/Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a method that makes use of ActiveRecord a moderate amount. I've always heard that unit testing methods and not using a database is the best way to go about things. However, the downsides of this to me are what if you incorrectly stub the response from ActiveRecord? I might incorrectly be stubbing out whatever ActiveRecord is returning in reality and now I have an inaccurate test.

FYI a `user` has many `coupons` and a `coupon` can have many `coupon_uses` (the times when it's applied to an `order`).

This is my method:

```
def get_coupons_and_uses_for_user
      coupons = Promotions::Coupon
        .includes(:coupon_uses)
        .where(user_id: user_id)

      coupons.reduce([]) do |memo, c|
        memo << { coupon: c, coupon_uses: c.coupon_uses.order('created_at desc') }
      end
    end
```

The above method (which basically queries the user's coupons and then returns each coupon associated with its usages) has two ActiveRecord calls, both of which I need to stub out if I don't use a database in my tests:

`Promotions::Coupon.includes(:coupon_uses).where(user_id: user_id)`

and

`c.coupon_uses.order('created_at desc') #The .order causes ActiveRecord to hit the database`

Here my test:

```
describe "#get_coupons_and_uses_for_user" do
    subject { service_instance.get_coupons_and_uses_for_user }

    let(:service_instance) { described_class.new(user_id) }
    let(:user_id) { 1 }
    let(:coupon1) { build_stubbed(:coupon) }
    let(:coupon2) { build_stubbed(:coupon) }
    let(:coupons) { [coupon1, coupon2] }
    let!(:coupon_use1) { build_stubbed(:coupon_use) }
    let!(:coupon_use2) { build_stubbed(:coupon_use) }
    let!(:coupon_use3) { build_stubbed(:coupon_use) }
    let!(:coupon_use4) { build_stubbed(:coupon_use) }

    before do
      allow(Promotions::Coupon).to receive_message_chain(:includes, :where) { coupons }
      allow(coupon1).to receive_message_chain(:coupon_uses, :order) { [coupon_use1, coupon_use2] }
      allow(coupon2).to receive_message_chain(:coupon_uses, :order) { [coupon_use3, coupon_use4] }
    end

    it "returns the user's coupons associated with their coupon uses" do
      expect(subject).to eq(
        [
          {
            coupon: coupon1,
            coupon_uses: [coupon_use1, coupon_use2]
          },
          {
            coupon: coupon2,
            coupon_uses: [coupon_use3, coupon_use4]
          }
        ]
      )
    end
  end
```

Is this a good way to test? Or should I be using a database? Why or why not?

The problem here is that I'm stubbing out the return values of my ActiveRecord calls like this:

```
allow(coupon1).to receive_message_chain(:coupon_uses, :order) { [coupon_use1, coupon_use2] }
```

But what if I'm wrong about what that query returns (imagine if the query were more complicated). Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing methods were lots of database queries in them. Is it okay to unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332283/testing-methods-were-lots-of-database-queries-in-them-is-it-okay-to-unit-test)

Answer (score 2):

No, do not stub the calls to the DB.

The Rails convention is to use the DB in your model tests. For better or worse it's what a Rails project is expected to to.

You don't have to follow convention, but it will make your life easier. So unless you have a compelling reason to do so, I would avoid it.

---

Why follow this convention? The convention of running model tests against the DB is good for a few reasons:

1. Developers familiar with Rails can get up to speed on the project faster when it follows convention (in this case they could debug/write tests work in a familiar way)
2. If the DB is slow in the tests, it will likely be slow in production, this will encourage good database design by giving you feedback during development.
3. Less code. Stubbing all the calls from an ActiveRecord model to the DB will become cumbersome, making refactoring more work to update all the method stubs when changing calls to ActiveRecord.
4. When you upgrade Rails, the interface to ActiveRecord might change, but the stubs will not. So your tests will pass while running against the DB in production could fail.

Comment: But why is convention good here? Why would it make things easier? If followed to an extreme.... I'm just gonna have a lot of slower tests in the long run.

Comment: Anyone else care to chime in? Is the idea that these tests are really integration tests?

Comment: Following @csexton's advice, not even upgrading Rails, but a routine database migration may cause code to break.

Stubbed calls may wrongly let specs pass because their view of the db is outdated. 

Also, by definition ActiveRecord is tied to the db. So I'd still consider it a unit test in the context of ActiveRecord. For the most part, we assume AR works. We're not going to write a write an AR spec that also runs a raw SQL query to check if the data is actually in the db.